# How can I create a NLog Config Timeshift by hours in C#?

Tags: c#, nlog

How can I, if possible, create a log file with a timestamp that is shifted by x hours?

```
<variable name="logdt" value="${shortdate}"/>
<targets>
    <target
        name="file" xsi:type="File"
        layout="${shortdate}${semi}${time}${semi}${message}"
        fileName="${basedir}\logs\${logdt}**-6h**.csv" 
        archiveFileName="${basedir}\archives\${logdt}**-6h**.{#}.zip"
        archiveEvery="Day"
        archiveNumbering="Rolling"
        maxArchiveFiles="7"
        enableArchiveFileCompression="true"
        keepFileOpen="true"
        openFileCacheTimeout="30"
    />
</targets>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the Time Source.

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Time-Source

Comment: Hi, I would recommend to paste the relevant code/text to this answer as this is currently could be seen as a link-only answer.

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288055/please-define-link-only-answer and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer